# Using re.sub with jinja2.Markup escaping in Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, escaping, jinja2

So I have the following function in my Flask app.

```
def markup_abbreviations(txt, match_map, match_regex):
    html = Markup.escape(txt)
    sub_template = Markup('<abbr title="%s">%s</abbr>')

    def replace_callback(m):
        return sub_template % (match_map[m.group(0)], m.group(0))

    return match_regex.sub(replace_callback, html)
```

Example arguments:

```
txt = 'blah blah blah etc., blah blah'

match_map = {
    'etc.': 'et cetera',
    'usu.': 'usually',
}

match_regex = re.compile(
    '|'.join(r'\b' + re.escape(k) for k in match_map)
)
```

This was working very well and turning `"etc."` into `"<abbr title=\"et cetera\">etc.</abbr>"` and so on in my local Python 3.3 machine.

Then I figure I want to deploy to Heroku, and it says it only supports the latest python, which is Python 3.6.1. It's different from the one I got locally, but, eh, whatever. It works... mostly.

Except my function above gives me `"&lt;abbr title=&quot;et cetera&quot;&gt;etc.&lt;/abbr&gt;"` now.

I assume between Python 3.3 and Python 3.6 the `re.sub` implementation must have changed somehow and now it no longer uses the passed string methods to create the output. So `Markup`'s auto-escaping methods aren't used. Instead a new `str` is built from scratch. Which is why `re.sub` only returns `str` now, and not `Markup` anymore.

How can I use `re.sub` with `jinja2.Markup` in Python 3.6 and make my function work once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Markup` class just "mark" string as safe for html. It means that the string doesn't have to be escaped when it placed in to the template.

When the `re.sub()` return new `str` object what you have to do is mark the new object as safe (wrap it in the Markup).

```
def markup_abbreviations(txt, match_map, match_regex):
    html = Markup.escape(txt)
    sub_template = '<abbr title="%s">%s</abbr>'

    def replace_callback(m):
        return sub_template % (match_map[m.group(0)], m.group(0))

    return Markup(match_regex.sub(replace_callback, html))
```

---

I check all "What's new" from Python 3.3 to 3.6 and there is nothing about changing behavior of `re` module (well there is something but it shouldn't be connected with your problem). Maybe someone else know what happend...

Comment: Ooh! You're right.`replace_callback` was returning escaped `Markup`, it was just `re.sub` that returned it as `str` Thanks!